# PHP SQL Syntax Check if theres a match

Tags: php

I am trying to query the db in php and get if there is a match / success but it's not resulting in success although it should so I've thinking there's a syntax error?

Here is the code:

```
if ($db_found) {
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM wp_users where user_login='.$user.'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

//Check if theres a match   
if $result > 0 {
        echo 'There was a match';
    }               

    ...
}
```

Comment: You are missing parens in your `if()` condition, but that won't give you the result you expect anyway. Use `mysql_num_rows($result) > 0`

Comment: mysql_query returns a result HANDLE, not the data from your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {
   echo 'There was a match';
 }
```

Comment: Tried the above too but same issue...it's always returning true

Comment: @Satch3000 maybe there's an error with your sql syntax, try this: 
`$SQL = "SELECT * FROM wp_users where user_login='".$user."'";`
Also be sure that there is no match in the database when you say s

Answer (score 3):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  echo 'match';
}
```

Comment: It seems to always be returning true, even if there's no match for some reason